# gensim model return ids not related with input doc2vec

Tags: word2vec, gensim, cosine-similarity, doc2vec

I created a model from mongodb db news and I tagged the documents by mongo collection id

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
i=0
docs=[]
for artical in lstcontent:
    doct = TaggedDocument(clean_str(artical), [lstids[i]])
    docs.append(doct)
    i+=1
```

after that I created the model by

```
pretrained_emb='tweet_cbow_300/tweets_cbow_300'
saved_path = "documentmodel/doc2vec_model.bin"
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
model = g.Doc2Vec(docs, size=vector_size, window=window_size, min_count=min_count, sample=sampling_threshold, workers=worker_count, hs=0, dm=dm, negative=negative_size, dbow_words=1, dm_concat=1, pretrained_emb=pretrained_emb, iter=train_epoch)
model.save(saved_path)
```

when I using the model by the code :

```
import gensim.models as g
import codecs
model="documentmodel/doc2vec_model.bin"
start_alpha=0.01
infer_epoch=1000
m = g.Doc2Vec.load(model)
sims = m.docvecs.most_similar(['5aa94578094b4051695eeb10'])
sims
```

the output is

```
[('5aa944c1094b4051695eeaef', 0.9255372881889343),
('5aa945c1094b4051695eeb1d', 0.9222575426101685),
('5aa94584094b4051695eeb12', 0.9210859537124634),
('5aa945d2094b4051695eeb20', 0.9083569049835205),
('5aa945c7094b4051695eeb1e', 0.905883252620697),
('5aa9458f094b4051695eeb14', 0.9054019451141357),
('5aa944c7094b4051695eeaf0', 0.9019848108291626),
('5aa94589094b4051695eeb13', 0.9012798070907593),
('5aa945b1094b4051695eeb1a', 0.9000773429870605),
('5aa945bc094b4051695eeb1c', 0.8999895453453064)]
```

the ids not related with 5aa94578094b4051695eeb10
where is my proplem !?

Comment: The built-in "simple_preprocess" utility can be used instead of clean_str function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be providing a string as the `words` of your `TaggedDocument` texts. It should be a list-of-words. (If you supply a string, it will see it as a list-of-single-character-words, and try to run the algorithm as character-to-character predictions – which won't lead to very good vectors.)

If you enable INFO level logging, and watch the output, you may see hints that this is the problem, in the form of a very small count of vocabulary words, dozens rather than tens-of-thousands. Or if that's not the problem, you may see other discrepancies that hint at what's going wrong.

Separate observations & tips:

- you're using a 'pretrained_emb' argument that's not part of standard gensim. If you're using an unofficial variant, based on an older gensim, you might have other issues. Pretrained word embeddings are *not* necessary for `Doc2Vec` to work, and may not offer much benefit. (I would always try without any such extra complications, first, then only after you have a simple approach working as a baseline, try such added tweaks and always evaluate if they're really helping or not.)
- it's unclear how many `iter` passes you're using, but 10-20 are typical values, perhaps more if your corpus is small and/or typical texts are short
- `dm=1, dm_concat=1` (PV-DM with a concatenative input layer) results in larger, slower models that may require much more data to become well-trained. It's not clear this `dm_concat=1` mode is ever worth the trouble. At best, it should be considered experimental. So I would get things working without it, before perhaps trying it as an advanced experiment.